# Как избежать повторной отправки формы при обновлении?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Дело в том, что после отправки пост запроса скрипт принимает отправленные данные, проверяет их на корректность (валидность, заполненность обязательных данных и т.д.) и выдает ответ – либо операция прошла успешно, либо произошла ошибка и список ошибок (например: ошибка — поле «имя» не заполнено. А на странице отправки уже в свою очередь выдается соответствующее сообщение: отправка успешна или не успешна.

Так вот есть ли элегантный вариант предотвратить повторную отправку формы?
Например мне пришла идея что если в javascript поймать событие обновления страницы(если такова есть отменить её и просто сделать переход по текущей ссылке.
Или если можно на сервере после получении данных POST запроса удалить какие нибудь информацию о запросе может она не будет повторно отправляться так как данные удалены?

А еще редирект не вариант. Так как после редиректа я не могу передать ответ скрипта.

А еще махинации с дополнительным полем с уникальным значением сохраненным на сессии и дальнейшая их проверка тоже крайний вариант.

Что скажете есть какие нибудь варианты?

Comment: Кстати Ajax тоже крайний вариант))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решением вопроса была запись ошибок в сессии, после редирект и после вывод ошибок из сессии и сразу удалить ее.
Так как я использую codeigniter в коде решения будет использован codeigniter но думаю суть будет ясна всем.
Пример записи ошибки:

```
        $phone_number = $this->input->post('phone_number');
        if (is_numeric($phone_number) && strlen($phone_number) == 9 && (int)$phone_number > 100000000) $value = $phone_number;
        else {
            $this->session->set_userdata('msg', array('ok' => 0, 'msg' => "Неверный формат номера телефона.<br>Номер должен указываться без пробелов, знаков тире или других знаков.<br>Например: 987654321", 'type' => "warning"));
            redirect('/user/config');
        }
```

Пример ловля, вывода и удаления ошибки из сессии:

```
if ($this->session->has_userdata('msg')) {
  $msg = $this->session->userdata('msg');
  $this->session->unset_userdata('msg');
  if (count($msg) && strlen($msg['msg']) > 0)
  {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-' .$msg['type'] .' alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="margin: 20px;"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'.$msg['msg'].'</div>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Чтобы было понятно, это вопрос уровня таблицы умножения в веб-программировании. И размышления вида "делать редирект или не делать" это все равно как если бы рассуждать "дважды два равное четыре не вариант. мне нужно пять".

После POST запроса всегда должен быть редирект. Точка. Переходим к делению в столбик.

> А еще редирект не вариант. Так как после редиректа я не могу передать ответ скрипта.

Ответ, если очень хочется его передать, пишется в сессию, и после редиректа оттуда показывается.

Впрочем, на большинстве современных сайтов (включая и этот) отправка формы осуществляется с помощью технологии AJAX, которая не требует перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: Я не согласен с вами что "После POST запроса всегда должен быть редирект. Точка." Я конечно понял что вы ооооочень умный человек раз равняете этот вопрос к 2+2, и что я оочень тупой что думаю 2+2=5. Но вы сами противоречите самому себе раз говорите что "После POST запроса всегда должен быть редирект. Точка." А потом говорите, что оказывается есть еще и ajax который решает проблему без редиректа. Это значит на редиректе не точка? @Ипатьев

Comment: @ShuhratjonJumaev при отправке формы AJAX'ом проблема просто перестаёт существовать, т. к. кнопка "Обновить" повторяет последний **синхронный** запрос, коим отправка формы не является. Раз для вас это "крайний вариант", то да, точка. И не потому, что других решений нет, а потому что из возможных это самое простое, а потому самое простое в обслуживании, отладке и доработке.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно точно узнать приймет ли сервер данные клиента - пробуйте сабмитить через Ajax, - если правильно сохраняете и переводите куда нужно. Если не удачный запрос - сразу можно показать клиенту корректную ошибку.

например что то типа

```
var jqxhr = $.post("example.php")
  .success(function() { alert("Успешное выполнение"); })
  .error(function() { alert("Ошибка выполнения"); })
  .complete(function() { alert("Завершение выполнения"); });
```

в коллбеках нужно получить нужную информацию которая пришла из сервера.

Тоесть ответ - не сабмитить форму на прямую а отсылать через асинхронно через Аякс. - Данные не будут отпарвляться повторно при перезагрузке

[линк](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

Answer (score 0):

На своём сайте я решил проблему заменой *Location* при сохранении результата:

```
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
header( "Refresh:5; url='#', true, 303);
```

покажет сообщение на 5 сек.