# При обновлении страницы, данные повторно записываются в БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Есть форма добавления товара в БД. Всё работает, все данные записываются, но при каждом обновлении данные повторно попадают в БД. Естественно повторно попадают те, что были введены в форму последними.

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col-6 px-5">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <h4>Русский</h4>
                <sub class="mt-3 ml-2"><em>*НЕ заполяйте те поля, которые не нужны</em></sub>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <input class="form-control my-3" type="text" name="furn_name_hy" placeholder="Имя товара">
                    <input class="form-control mb-3" type="text" name="furn_size_hy" placeholder="Размер (xx)">
                    <input class="form-control mb-3" type="text" name="furn_material_hy" placeholder="Материал">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <input class="form-control my-3" type="text" name="furn_diameter_hy" placeholder="Диаметр">
                    <input class="form-control mb-3" type="text" name="furn_height_hy" placeholder="Высота">
                    <input class="form-control mb-3" type="text" name="furn_color_hy" placeholder="Цвет">
                </div>
                <input class="form-control mx-3" type="text" name="furn_manuf_hy" placeholder="Страна производителя">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 px-5">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <h4>Английский</h4>
                <sub class="mt-3 ml-2"><em>*Не заполяйте те поля, которые не нужны</em></sub>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <input class="form-control my-3" type="text" name="furn_name_en" placeholder="Name">
                    <input class="form-control mb-3" type="text" name="furn_size_en" placeholder="Size (xx)">
                    <input class="form-control mb-3" type="text" name="furn_material_en" placeholder="Material">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <input class="form-control my-3" type="text" name="furn_diameter_en" placeholder="Diameter">
                    <input class="form-control mb-3" type="text" name="furn_height_en" placeholder="Height">
                    <input class="form-control mb-3" type="text" name="furn_color_en" placeholder="Color">
                </div>
                <input class="form-control mx-3" type="text" name="furn_manuf_en" placeholder="Country of the manufacturer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex col-6 mx-auto">
        <input class="form-control m-3" type="text" name="furn_price" placeholder="Цена">
        <div class="custom-file m-3">
            <input class="custom-file-input" id="chooseImg" type="file" name="furn_image">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="chooseImg">Картинка</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary d-block mx-auto" type="submit" name="add_furn">Добавить продукт</button>
</form>
```

```php
    $furnUpload = $_FILES['furn_image']['name'];
    $furnUploadTmp = $_FILES['furn_image']['tmp_name'];
    $furnUploadExt = strtolower(end(explode('.', $furnUpload)));
    $furnUploadName = uniqid().".".$furnUploadExt;
    $furnUploadDestination = 'uploads/'.$furnUploadName;
    move_uploaded_file($furnUploadTmp, $furnUploadDestination);

    $addFurn = $_POST['add_furn'];
    $furnNameHy = $_POST['furn_name_hy'];
    $furnNameEn = $_POST['furn_name_en'];
    $furnPrice = $_POST['furn_price'];
    $furnDiameterHy = $_POST['furn_diameter_hy'];
    $furnSizeHy = $_POST['furn_size_hy'];
    $furnHeightHy = $_POST['furn_height_hy'];
    $furnMaterHy = $_POST['furn_material_hy'];
    $furnColorHy = $_POST['furn_color_hy'];
    $furnManufHy = $_POST['furn_manuf_hy'];
    $furnDiameterEn = $_POST['furn_diameter_en'];
    $furnSizeEn = $_POST['furn_size_en'];
    $furnHeightEn = $_POST['furn_height_en'];
    $furnMaterEn = $_POST['furn_material_en'];
    $furnColorEn = $_POST['furn_color_en'];
    $furnManufEn = $_POST['furn_manuf_en'];
    
    if (isset($addFurn)) {
        $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `furniture` (`name_hy`, `name_en`, `price`, `image`, `diameter_hy` `size_hy`, `height_hy`, `material_hy`, `color_hy`, `manuf_hy`, `diameter_en`, `size_en`, `height_en`, `material_en`, `color_en`, `manuf_en`)
                       VALUES('$furnNameHy', '$furnNameEn', '$furnPrice', '$furnUploadDestination', '$furnDiameterHy', '$furnSizeHy', '$furnHeightHy', '$furnMaterHy', '$furnColorHy', '$furnManufHy', '$furnDiameterEn' '$furnSizeEn', '$furnHeightEn', '$furnMaterEn', '$furnColorEn', '$furnManufEn')");
    }
```

Я попробовал сделать `unset()` массиву `$_POST`, кнопке submit, как внутри if, так и в самом конце кода, но нечего. Простите, если это слишком глупый вопрос, я как и многие здесь—новичок.

Comment: Ещё одна жертва favicon.ico, фавикон есть на сайте? :) p.s. хотя это не спасёт: с яблока зайдут там другую запросит))) Роутер нужен нормальный.

Comment: Вы что, про это `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/clock2.png">`? Какая вообще разница?

Comment: favicon есть? В инструментах разраба браузера глянь что выдает: 404 - не?

Comment: @АртёмРыженький Не выдаёт

Comment: @aleksandr barakin плак

Comment: @dvtpetrosyan вот ты пишешь ... но при каждом обновлении данные повторно попадают в БД ... это просто обновление или есть сообщение о повторной отправке и ты согласился - нажал кнопку на повторную отправку?

Comment: @АртёмРыженький никаких сообщений о повторной отправке нет, просто делаю refresh страницы и последние данные опять появляются в бд, тоесть создаётся 
вторая записи с отличным от предыдущего id, но с одинаковым содержанием

Comment: обнов страницы с закрученной стрелкой около поисквого поля-Refresh, Ctrl+R, Ctrl+Shift+R, F5

Comment: @dvtpetrosyan ну это больше всего похоже на косяк: точка входа - favicon, которой нет, либо так называемый синглтон - не синглтон

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543779/Как-избежать-повторной-отправки-формы-при-обновлении

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как избежать повторной отправки формы при обновлении?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543779/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

Такое поведение часто происходит, когда браузер запоминает данные. Некоторые браузеры не спрашивают подтверждения повторной отправки данных, либо эта настройка выключена. Чтобы такого не происходило, необходимо после успешного добавления данных в БД делать перенаправление на страницу этой самой записи или снова на форму добавления. Тогда можно будет сколько угодно раз обновлять страницу и ничего не будет добавляться.
Если после добавления надо отобразить какое-то сообщение (успех или ошибка), то это сообщение можно записать в сессию, отобразить после загрузки страницы и удалить из сессии.