# Как сделать так, чтобы данные, введенные форму не заносились в БД повторно после перезагрузки страницы и допустимо ли такое поведение на сайте?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица users в БД по имени temp1.
В users есть два столбца: name и surname.
Через форму вводятся имя и фамилия. Данные успешно заносятся в БД. Но обратил внимание, что если перезагрузить страницу и принять повторную отправку формы, то данные еще раз заносятся в БД.

**Насколько это поведение приемлемо для сайта? Считается ли это багом? Как это исправить?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style rel="stylesheet">
            label {
                width: 150px;
            }
            .input-area {
                margin-bottom: 15px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="input-area">
                <label>Имя</label>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="input-area">
                <label>Фамилия</label>
                <input type="text" name="surname">
            </div>
            <div class="input-area">
                <input type="submit" value="Занести данные в базу">
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=temp1", "root", "");
                $name = htmlentities(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $surname = htmlentities(trim($_POST["surname"]));
            
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, surname) VALUES(?, ?)");
                $stmt->execute([$name, $surname]);
        ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: После записи данных делайте редирект на какую нибудь другую страницу, с пустой формой или например на страницу где информация только отображается, но не редактируется. И даже в этом случае запись может повториться, просто потому что будет плохая связь и браузер решит сам повторить запрос. Считать ли багом - решать вам в зависимости от поставленной задачи. Как защищаться то же зависит от конечной задачи. например заранее открыть сессию и пометить в сессии что она уже привязана к пользователю, после того как пользователя записали. И не делать запись, если id есть в сессии

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как избежать повторной отправки формы при обновлении?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543779/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: @Mike спасибо, получилось реализовать через сессию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=temp1", "root", "");
                    $name = htmlentities(trim($_POST["name"]));
                    $surname = htmlentities(trim($_POST["surname"]));
                    
                    $pdo->query("BEGIN");
                

                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, surname) VALUES(?, ?)");
                    $stmt->execute([$name, $surname]);
                    $result = $pdo->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
                    $user_id = $result->fetch()[0];
                    echo $user_id . " ";
                    if (isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
                       echo $_SESSION["id"];
                    }
                    if ($user_id - 1 == $_SESSION["id"]) {
                       $pdo->query("ROLLBACK");
                       echo "<script>alert('Не надо отправлять форму еще раз!')</script>";
                       $_SESSION["id"] = $user_id;
                       die();
                    } 
                    $_SESSION["id"] = $user_id;
                    $pdo->query("COMMIT");
            }
            
        ?>
```