# Почему после удаления файла он снова появляется?

Tags: php, html, файлы

Ситуация такая. Загружаю файл в папку, файл загружен. Удаляю файл, перезагружаю страницу, файл опять появляется. Как это убрать?

```php
<?php
    $status = "";
    $filename_x = "Choose File";
    $allowedMIMETypes = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
    $flag = 1;

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['name']);
        if ($check !== false) {
            $flag = 1;
        } else {
            $flag = 0;
        }
    }

    if (file_exists(basename($_FILES['file']['name']))) {
        $status = "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $flag = 0;
    }

    if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 500000) {
        $status = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $flag = 0;
    }

    if(!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), $allowedMIMETypes)) {
        $status = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $flag = 0;
    }

    if ($flag == 0) {
        $status = "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], basename($_FILES['file']['name']))) {
            $status = htmlspecialchars(basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            $status = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=JetBrains+Mono:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="file"><?php echo $filename_x?></label><br>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"><br>
                <input id="file" type="file" name="file">
            </form>
            <p><?php echo $status?></p>
            <?php
                $path = scandir(getcwd());
                $restrictions = array('.', '..', 'index.css', 'index.php');
                foreach ($path as $f){
                    if(!in_array($f, $restrictions) and !is_dir($f)) echo "<a href='".$f."'>".$f."</a>"."<br>";
                    if(!in_array($f, $restrictions) and is_dir($f)) echo "<a href='".$f."'>".$f."/</a>"."<br>";
                }
            ?>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
<br>
```

Comment: После загрузки файла надо делать `header('Location: СТРАНИЦА С ФОРМОЙ');
exit;`  чтобы очистить все отсылаемые данные........ А если нужно статус отсылать, то при таком коде придётся это делать в get параметре........ну или **в сессии**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как избежать повторной отправки формы при обновлении?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543779/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: А при чем здесь input? В input после перезагрузки страницы файл НИКОГДА не появляется. Максимум, что у вас остается - это ссылка на файл. Если речь про неё, то так и надо спрашивать. Почему вы решили, что файл удаляется?

Comment: Форма отправляется повторно, нужно делать редирект после сохранения файла, например, header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); exit;